# play2.0 dist getting errors

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a scala / play 2.0.4 application running. Locally everything is fine, and I can start the service via "play run".
Now I want to export the application to prod server. I used the play command "dist", and unzipped the files on the server.
But if I start the service, I get an exception on several actions:

```
play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com..webapp.services.Backend.getCitiesByName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;]]
at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play.play_2.9.1-play_2.9.1-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play.play_2.9.1-play_2.9.1-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor-akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play.play_2.9.1-play_2.9.1-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor-akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor-akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:179) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor-akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:516) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor-akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor-akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor-akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1479) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor-akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor-akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
```

The method not found is actually in code available, and works on my local installation (via play run). It's a class and method from a dependency from the Scala project (included in lib as a jar).

I cleaned all references and built all dependencies before I used "dist".

Can anybody give me a hint where to search for this error?
would be really great help!

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the dependent JAR file is not making it to your distribution ZiP file

For play to add the dependent JARs into your distribution package, you need to add it to the project/Build.scala file. See if the dependency in question is available on Maven, and add it to the Build.scala file like this:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
      "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.20",
 )
```